# $(g-2)/2$ The anomalous magnetic moment

Tags: quantum-field-theory, standard-model, magnetic-moment

Does anyone know how to calculate the anomalous magnetic moment of the muon?
The Fermilab result is 3 standard deviations from the standard model calculated value. Quantum electrodynamics to 10th order, hadronic vacuum polarizations, and light-by-light have at least not come up to the latest results $a =$ 0.00116 591 040...

Comment: Technically, just write diagrams and then compute them. Conceptually, check "An anomalous moment for the muon" at CERN Courier as the starting point + book "The Anomalous Magnetic Moment of the Muon" by Friedrich Jegerlehner (Spinger, 2017) for the detailed review

Comment: Do you understand the one-loop computation?

Comment: Thanks Artem 

Comment: Ghoster: I'm sure I'd understand.. what is it?

Comment: Have you done any QFT work in your own studies? That statement seems somewhat contradictory at first glance, you say you'd be sure you would understand it but then ask what it is. You could only be sure to understand if you've done QFT work before (or are currently studying it in which case maybe you haven't covered Feynman diagrams yet).

Comment: In [Srednicki](https://web.physics.ucsb.edu/~mark/ms-qft-DRAFT.pdf) the calculation is done in chapters 62, 63, and 64. Figure 62.3 is the relevant Feynman diagram. At one loop the result is the same for the electron and the muon.

Comment: The calculation to 10th order probably involves person-decades or person-centuries of work.

Comment: don't for get the hadronic content